# MergeSort not giving correct output

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, mergesort

I have two classes:

```
public class List {
    public Node _head;
}
```

And:

```
public class Node {
    public String _word;
    public Node _next;
}
```

I have a constructor in "List", which gets a String as a parameter and puts every word in a seperate Node, like this:

```
public List(String text) {
    if (text.length() == 0)
        _head = null;
    createList(text);
}

private void createList(String text) {
    int lastIndex=0; 
    String temp;        
    for (int i=0;i<text.length();i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i)==' '|| i==text.length()-1) {
            if (i == 0) { // Space in the begining
                lastIndex=1;
                continue;
            }
            if (i == text.length()-1) { // If we reached to the last char of the string

                if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') { // If it's a space, don't include it
                    temp = text.substring(lastIndex,i);
                } else {
                    temp = text.substring(lastIndex,i+1);
                }
            } else {
                temp = text.substring(lastIndex,i);
            }
            addToBegining(temp);
            lastIndex=i+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, when I'm trying to use a mergesort on the linked list, I can't manage to get it working.

This is the sorting code:

```
public Node merge_sort(Node h) {
    if (h == null || h._next == null) { return h; }
    Node middle = getMiddle(h);      //get the middle of the list
    Node sHalf = middle._next; middle._next = null;   //split the list into two halfs

    return merge(merge_sort(h), merge_sort(sHalf));  //recurse on that
}

public Node merge(Node a, Node b) {
    Node dummyHead, curr; 
    dummyHead = new Node(); 
    curr = dummyHead;
    while (a !=null && b!= null) {
        if (a._word.compareTo(b._word) <= 0) { 
            curr._next = a; 
            a = a._next; 
        } else { 
            curr._next = b; 
            b = b._next; 
        }
        curr = curr._next;
    }
    curr._next = (a == null) ? b : a;
    return dummyHead._next;
}

public Node getMiddle(Node h) {
    if (h == null) { return h; }
    Node slow, fast; 
    slow = fast = h;
    while (fast._next != null && fast._next._next != null) {
        slow = slow._next; 
        fast = fast._next._next;
    }
    return slow;
}
```

Any idea what's wrong?
I'm trying to make a new TextList with the String "Hello New World A Dawn Is There" and Output is: "There World"..

Comment: Why do you reinvent the linked list and sorting? Can't you just use `java.util.LinkedList` and `java.util.Collections.sort`?

Comment: @kosmaty I think he is learning to implement LinkedList. Did you try printing the data before the sorting? Just to check if all your content is actually there in the LinkedList

Comment: I'm trying to learn the interface. I did, and it comes out good  (just reversed). After I'm trying to sort, the output is just messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Please change as below. I think you forgot to assign the `curr` node to the appropriate values after the `if-else`.

```
    public Node merge(Node a, Node b)
    {
        Node dummyHead, curr;
        dummyHead = new Node();
        curr = dummyHead;
        while (a != null && b != null)
        {
            if (a._word.compareTo(b._word) <= 0)
            {
                curr._next = a;
                curr = a;
                a = a._next;
            }
            else
            {
                curr._next = b;
                curr = b;
                b = b._next;
            }
            curr = curr._next;
        }
        curr._next = (a == null) ? b : a;
        return dummyHead._next;
    }
```

Comment: @Osh24 Can you try printing values which are getting calculate and passed from the `merge_sort` function.

Comment: You mean adding System.out.print inside the recursive function? I'm not sure of which values..

Answer (score -1):

Merge sort is not suitable for Linked List as you need acces to middle element of your list (you divide list into 2 sublists). With linked list you have access only to first element of the list (singly-linked list).

It is not feasible to try to use it, as you have to first find a link to middle element every time you divide your list. Better try insertion sort or quick-sort with 1st element of linked list as a pivot.

**EDIT:**
Yesterday, I replied from my phone and had no way to analyse your code.

Today I tested your code.

I create input list with words `"ant", "lion", "pig", "rat", "bat", "tiger", "cat", "dog"` and use `merge_sort()` method.
Output of it was nicely sorted list.

The only alternations to your code I did, was adding constructors to `Node()` class

```
Node () {
    _word = "";
    _next = null;
}

Node (String word) {
    _word = word;
}
```

but that was only for me to make it easier create new node.

Can you show how do you test your output list?

**EDIT2:**
I didn't checked your code to separate words from string as you stated it works)

**EDIT3:**
Your merge method have also other problems but this one is the main one.

Think how your `merge()` method is working when you try to merge 2 list:
a = { "ant", "bat", "dog"}
b = { "cat", "lion", "rat"}

while loop iterations:

1. curr = {"ant"} a = { "bat", "dog" } b = { "cat", "lion", "rat"}
2. curr = {"ant", "bat"} a = { "dog" } b = { "cat", "lion", "rat"}
3. curr = {"ant" "bat", "cat"} a = { "dog"} b = { "lion", "rat" }
4. curr = {"ant", "bat", "cat", "dog"} a = { } b = { "lion", "rat" }
5. a == null, while loop terminated

what happened next?
Your method assign only one time next element from list b and exit. Loosing 2nd element ("rat") from b.

**I changed your code slightly, `getMiddle()` method is same as yours:**

```
public Node mergeSort(Node h) {
    if (h._next != null) { // check for recursion if in list left at least 2 elements
        Node middle = getMiddle(h);
        Node sHalf = middle._next; middle._next = null;
        return merge(mergeSort(h), mergeSort(sHalf));
    }
    else { // if only 1 element then no need to sort
        return h;
    }
}

public Node merge(Node a, Node b) {
    Node dummyHead = new Node();
    Node curr = dummyHead; 
    while (a !=null && b!= null) {
        if (a._word.compareTo(b._word) <= 0) {
            curr._next= a; 
            a = a._next; 
        } else { 
            curr._next = b; 
            b = b._next;            
        }
        curr = curr._next;
    }
    // if list a still has some elements, insert them to the end of the curr
    while(a != null) {
        curr._next = a; 
        a = a._next; 
        curr = curr._next;
    }
    // if list b still has some elements, insert them to the end of the curr
    while(b != null) {
        curr._next = b; 
        b = b._next;
        curr = curr._next;
    }
    return dummyHead._next;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have access to all the elements using an iteration? I think the OP is using the `getMiddle()` function.

Comment: Your recommendation to use other list is valid, but the user is learning implementation. Please assist on the requirement of the question.

Comment: I'm not saying is not possible, but is not suitable. Using merge sort for linked list is not effective, as every time you divide your list you need to iterate trough list to find middle element.

Comment: I understand, and that's what the user wants. He is not concerned about effectiveness of the program as much as learning of the same. :)

Comment: I'm trying to do that with O(nlogn).

Comment: @Osh24 I'm not expert but I don't think that your algorithm will be O(nlogn) efficient. You need to iterate  your list ((O(n))every time you split it on half (each time you need to find middle element). It would be more like n^2logn, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @MarcinKruglik Going through the String and adding each word to a Node is O(n). Then, merge sorting the list by recursion is O(nlogn), total of  O(nlogn)..

Comment: @MarcinKruglik
That's the code I'm running from my main:

      `String s = "ant lion pig rat bat tiger cat dog";
      TextList list = new TextList(s);
      System.out.println("Pre-sort: " + list);
      list.merge_sort(list.getHead());
      System.out.println("Post-sort: " + list);`

The output is:
Pre-sort: dog cat tiger bat rat pig lion ant 
Post-sort: dog lion pig rat tiger

Comment: @Osh24 1. In merge sort, where you have direct acces to middle element, like in array, indeed effieciency is O(nlogn), but here you need to iterate list each time you are recursively calk merge_sort() to find middle element, which is O(n).

Comment: @Osh24 2. Your list is sorted then. Where is the problem?

Comment: I think your problem is in 2 last lines of your `merge()` method.

Comment: @Osh24 I changed your code slightly and now is working (i tested it for several input lists). Please check EDIT3